# Compare multiple columns from differemt dataframes with same length Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, multiple-columns

I have four dataframes with the following structure:

```py
df1
   max_proba    chosen_class
0   0.8            class_A
1   0.92           class_B
2   0.82           class_B
3   0.74           class_B
4   0.58           class_A

df2
   max_proba    chosen_class
0   0.6            class_C
1   0.62           class_D
2   0.87           class_D
3   0.94           class_C
4   0.62           class_D

# ... and same for df3 and df4 only chosen class values and probabilities that change!
```

I want to compare between columns "max_proba" between all the 4 dataframes and keep the maximum value with it's chosen class.

( for example: one sample, if df1 max_proba = 0,23 ,df2 max_proba =  0,86, df3 max_proba = 0,56, df4 max_proba = 76 ==> here I want only the chosen class with highest probability 0,86 which can be class_E (for example))

Comment: Can you add the expected output for your input dataframes (df1 and df2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to compare them row by row.

You should join them into one data frame:

```
df = df1.append(df2)
```

Then make a new columns 'index' with number of row in previous dataframes and column 'level_0' with number of row in this dataframe:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.reset_index()
```

And find the indexes of rows with maximum for each index:

```
indexes = df.groupby('index').apply(lambda x: x.max_proba == max(x['max_proba'])).reset_index()
```

Finally, select rows with maximum max_proba from the big data frame with our indexes:

```
result = df.loc[indexes[indexes.max_proba].level_1.values]
```

The output will be like:

```
level_0 index   max_proba   chosen_class
0   0   0   0.80    class_A
1   1   1   0.92    class_B
7   7   2   0.87    class_D
8   8   3   0.94    class_C
9   9   4   0.62    class_D
```

You can drop extra columns with function **drop**.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, yes exactly comparing row by row. Is this valid for more than two dataframes? and one other thing in case we have equal probabilities the class will be affected randomly? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: In case of four data frames you just should join all of them into one, so it will work fine: df = df1.append(df2.append(df3.append(df4))). I should warn you that I suspect it's not the easiest way to solve your issue, but I didn't managed to do it better )

Comment: About the same probabilities, I guess, it will select the value, depending on index, but I'm not sure, I should check

Comment: @Legna And if my answer will be useful for you, you can accept it

Comment: @Legna I have checked about equal values. It will choose the value with the smallest index (which goes first).